# hibernate - delete hql in eclipse hibernate tool

Tags: hibernate

I tried to execute a delete query as following in eclipse's HQL tool

```
delete from Address address where address.id = 6
```

but i got the

```
org.hibernate.hql.QueryExecutionRequestException: Not supported for DML operations
```

Please tell me that i've done wrong.
Thank you.

Answer (score 24):

Try the annotation `@Modifying` on the update method.

Comment: As per [Spring documentation](https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/jpa/docs/current/reference/html/#jpa.modifying-queries), whenever you add custom behavior for modifying queries that only need parameter binding then use `@Modifying` annotation

Answer (score 3):

I had same issue.  Your issue is not for using DML... the first suggestion posted a link for a solution for DML, but your question is for SQL.

This works below for SQL.

```
String sql = "delete from ServiceProviderMapping where id=7";
Query query = hibernateSession.createQuery(sql);
query.executeUpdate();
```

Answer (score 1):

Please try the following:

```
final String hql = "delete from Job where jobId = :id";
Query query = session.createQuery(hql).setLong("id", jobId);

query.executeUpdate();
```

Answer (score 0):

[This post](https://forum.hibernate.org/viewtopic.php?f=1&t=982958&view=previous) suggests trying to open a session manually, and then run the delete.